# jQuery moving element in the DOM when you have repeating containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I move an element in the dom when I have multiple containers with the same id and classes? I want to move the element with class  one below the element with class two.

I first tried

```
$('.one').insertAfter('.two');
```

But this inserts the amount of .one elements in my DOM after each element with the class .two. How do I only move the element inside its own container? To clarify - I want to move the element in both containers.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
 </div>
```

Edit: wrote out ids for containers instead of classes. Fixed.

Comment: It's bad html to have different dom elements with the same id (it's perfectly fine with classes).

Comment: Use unique ID (and many classes with same name is acceptable). For your case you can use ":eq(n)" in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, IDs must be unique on document context, use class instead:

```
<div class="container">...</div>
```

Then, you could use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method instead using function:

```
$('.two').after(function () {
    return $(this).closest('.container').children('.one');
});
```

Using [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method, you'd need a `each` loop:

```
$('.one').each(function () {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('.container').children('.two'));
});
```

[-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/x7u0ah2h/)

Comment: If the elements isnt children - but still in the same parent container, how would I do it then?

Comment: You mean not direct descendant or what? If ya, use `.find('.two')` instead. If not, provide concrete sample (HTML markup)